# Change menu icon position HTML/CSS with FlexBox Grid

Tags: html, css

I have a menu icon which is displayed when window reaches certain size.
Everything is fine but the position of this icon. I don't know how to get this to the right side of the site - the most favourable would be to define the `right` property.
Here's what it look like now:
[image]

And I would like it to be really close to the right boundary of the window.
Here's the code:

**HTML**:

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-1">
            <img src="images/logo.svg">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-offset-1">
            <div class="iconcont">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="header()" >
                    <div class="bar"></div>
                    <div class="bar"></div>
                    <div class="bar"></div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="menu" id="mainmenu">
                <a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a>
                <a href="#news">News</a>
                <a href="#people">Members</a>
                <a href="#history">History</a>
                <a href="#projects">Projects</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
/* HEADER */
.header {
    background-image: url("images/stars.png");
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;

}

header img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

/* MENU */

.menu {
    background-color: transparent;
    overflow: hidden;
}


.icon {
    display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1370px) {
    .menu a {
        display: none;
    }

    .icon {
        display: block;
    }
}

.iconcont {
    top: 55px;
    position: relative;
}
```

I tried to wrap it in div (iconcont) but the right or left property doesn't work as I want. I guess it's because the whole menu is `"col-xs-offset-1"` (Flexbox Grid) but I don't know how to fix this and not ruin everything else.

**EDIT:**
For anyonewondering I fixed it. I put the icon in another div `col-offset-5` but AFTER menu. I don't know why I hadn't done it in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe add an ID to the class you want special treatment for and then make an exception with that?

HTML

```
<div class="col-xs-offset-1" id="header-layout">
    <div class="iconcont">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="header()" >
            <div class="bar"></div>
            <div class="bar"></div>
            <div class="bar"></div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu" id="mainmenu">
        <a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a>
        <a href="#news">News</a>
        <a href="#people">Members</a>
        <a href="#history">History</a>
        <a href="#projects">Projects</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
    @media screen and (max-width: 1370px) {

    #header-layout
    {   display: flex;
        align-items: flex-end;
    }

}
```

Comment: Dind't work, I guess I just fiddle with it more and maybe something happens